# ngResource.save() not calling error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm using angular 1.2 and am having difficulty handling any type of error. The documentation says that I can use 2 callbacks on the `save` method, the 1st as a success callback and the 2nd as an error callback. However, the 1st is only ever getting called. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var obj = new ResourcefulObjThing();
obj.$save(
  function () { alert('success'); }, // no matter the status code, this will get called
  function () { alert('failure'); }
);

ResourcefulObjThing.save(
  {},
  function () { alert('success'); }, // no matter the status code, this will get called
  function () { alert('failure'); }
);

var obj = new ResourcefulObjThing();
obj.$save().then(
  function () { alert('success'); }, // no matter the status code, this will get called
  function () { alert('failure'); }
);

$http
  .post('/resourceful/url', {})
  .success(function () { alert('success'); } // no matter the status code, this will get called
  .error(function () { alert('error'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a httpInterceptor that wasn't rejecting an error.